# script or powershell or batch file to select and connect to a specific SSID

Tags: wireless-networking, batch, powershell

Is anyone aware of a way in windows 10 to programmatically select (i.e. connect to) a specific SSID/wiFi network?  I have a couple of use/test cases where I need to connect to different SSID's at different points in the process.

I'm mostly flexible on the exact method (batch file, powershell script, registry hack, etc.) as long as it's something I can automate within some type of script.

To be extra-pedantic: I **do** need the script to both connect to that SSID and also get a DHCP address as if I had clicked on "connect" with the mouse.

The very simplified version of the script will be something like this:

1. do some stuff
2. connect to SSID/network "foo"
3. either sleep long enough to ensure we've gotten an IP address, or (maybe more ideally) wait for an event?
4. do some more different stuff
5. connect to SSID/network "bar"
6. again wait/verify that we've switched and gotten a new IP address from the "bar" network
7. do some more other different stuff.

Comment: Superuser is not a script writing service. :)

Comment: Your snark is noted, but I didn't need (nor ask for) someone to write the script.  The piece of information i was looking for is the existence of "netsh" and specifically "netsh wlan (dis)connect".  The fact that phyrfox took time to write out the actual control flow and syntax is extremely helpful (I work in bash/unix, not windows batch.... but I certainly could have found all that stuff for myself.)

Comment: If you searched for "windows connect to wifi command line" you would have found the answer straight away. That's one of the reasons we don't write scripts. You are expected to at least make some kind of effort.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): which says (amongst other things) "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a normal batch file (note: you might need elevated privileges to run the script). The basic process might look like this:

```
netsh wlan connect <name>
wait1:
ping -n 1 <server.name>
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto action1
goto wait1
action1:
<do something interesting here>
netsh wlan disconnect
netsh wlan connect <name2>
wait2:
ping -n 1 <server.name2>
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto action2
goto wait2
action2:
<do something interesting here>
```

If you want to introduce a timed delay, you can also do something like:

```
ping -n 10 ::1 > nul
```

This gives you a 10 second delay and discards the output.